# How to get a plane to emit an object in a fluid simulation?

Tags: animation, particles, fluid-simulation

I have a question about making a plane emit an object as a particle.

So I am making this scene where balloons are going to fly through a subway corridor and I am trying to make the particles come out of a plane but when I bake the simulation, nothing comes out of it.
[image: The plane the particles are supposed to come out of are at the top of the stairs]

Here is the [.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-A0CJ2x_tTBXOUYQ6stdCrMn4nTdBJI/view?usp=sharing) file so you can take a look at it.

Comment: you accidentally posted the blend1 which is the previous version of the file so no particles

Comment: Oh I'm sorry let me fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use a particle simulation or something like that, because fluid simulations look good as mesh but as particles that have objects they usually don't look very good.

in order to get the collisions to work you might want to get the molecular script addon and learn how to use it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLDCr9734r8

this is a video that explains how to make a bunch of balls but if in the particle settings you set gravity to negative and the corridor to a collider you can get it to look like balloons

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the addon and well see if it works!